# Installed new battery driver and lost all power at reboot

Tags: motherboard

Battery was bad on sony vaio laptop...bought replacement...came with instalation disk(assume drivers) when asked to reboot, nothing...no power lights for a/c or battery. Replaced a/c socket. nothing. Another tech said maybe it cooked the bios. How do I reinstall the bios onto a motherboard that has no power? Or maybe other thoughts? Thanks

Comment: "Battery driver"? You've been had.

Comment: @Ignacio: I agree.  There are ACPI drivers for batteries, but those don't get involved until OS startup... no software configuration would stop a computer from powering on.

Answer (score 0):

The battery may not be charged, and some laptops won't power up if a battery is completely empty (even when they have AC power).  So, try leaving the laptop, with its new battery installed, plugged in but powered off so that the battery can charge.  Check back an hour later and see if powers up.

(I've seen this a couple of times among a few clients, and so I'm hoping this is all that your problem is.)

P.S.:  Batteries don't have drivers.  Changing the battery is all you should have needed to do.